# Actionscript 3.0 использование FlashVars

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

Возникла проблема, суть которой в следующем:

**HTML**

```
<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='/test.swf'>
<param name='flashvars' value='var1=привет ребята' />
</object>
```

**ActionScript**

```
var text_1 = loaderInfo.parameters.var1;
if(text_1 != null && text_1 != "") {
    movik_my_text.text = text_1; // здесь чего-то не хватает
}
```

Дело в том, что принятый через FlashVars текст, почему-то не вставляется во флэшке. Или вставляется, но с какими-то искажениями(или выводится неполный текст). Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Решение найдено. Для textField нужно было выставить значение "Шрифты устройства". У меня же стояло "Сглаживание для читаемости".

Answer (score 0):

Во всех ситуациях кроме "Шрифты устройства" надо внедрять шрифт в swf-ку.
Можно это сделать в самом редакторе Flash(Animate).
https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/animate/using/embed-fonts-consistent-text-appearance.html

Если TextField создаётся кодом, то по умолчанию он будет использовать "Шрифты устройства", т.е. свойство embedFonts будет false.